# How to stop parse in Scrapy SitemapSpider

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, sitemap

My requirement is to get all the url present in sitemap.xml, scrapy sitemapspider class does the task but it also try to parse the pages which makes the crawling slow as it try to download the entire page.

Is their a way to get just the url's without going into each one of them.

Comment: I think you can use link extractor which just extracts the links from the page and not download them. Later you can dump this data to a file or something. - http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more what you want to do? You wan to go to sitemap.xml and extract all of the links from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract urls from sitemap by using `scrapy.utils.sitemap.Sitemap` object, which does everything for you.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.utils.sitemap import Sitemap


class SitemapJustUrlsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "sitemap_spider"
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        s = Sitemap(response.body)
        for sitelink in s:
            url = sitelink['loc']
            yield {'url': url}
```

Then to save the urls just: `scrapy crawl sitemap_spider -o urls.json`